# Is it possible to use Docker for Linux in a matrix of operating systems?

Tags: docker, github-actions

GitHub Actions let us [define matrices to launch several variations of a single job](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/using-a-matrix-for-your-jobs). For instance for starting a job on two operating systems:

```
name: Build
on:
  push
    branches: [ main ]
jobs:
  build:
    strategy:
      matrix:
        os: [ubuntu-latest, macos-latest]
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}
    steps:
      - (…)
```

GitHub Actions also let us [use a Docker container on Linux](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/running-jobs-in-a-container):

```
name: Build
on:
  push
    branches: [ main ]
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    container: my-docker/container:0.1.0
    steps:
      - (…)
```

Is it possible to use both at the same time: running a job on several operating systems using matrices, and using a Docker container specifically for Linux? Something among the lines of (*this code is invalid*):

```
name: Build
on:
  push
    branches: [ main ]
jobs:
  build:
    strategy:
      matrix:
        os: [ubuntu-latest, macos-latest]
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}
    container:
      if: matrix.os == 'ubuntu-latest'
      image: my-docker/container:0.1.0
    steps:
      - (…)
```

This code is not correct because `container` cannot have a `if` keyword. If I remove the `if`, the code is correct but the job will fail on macOS runners (which cannot run Docker). How do I enable `container` for Linux and disable it for everything else? I found no information at all about this use case in the documentation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Paired values in github actions matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66025220/paired-values-in-github-actions-matrix)

Comment: @jonrsharpe I am afraid no, this does not explain how I can use the `container` directive only for Linux. For example a macOS runner will see this directive and fail while trying to run a Docker command.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73953210/12555857

Comment: @rkochar I do not understand how this can solve the problem, can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could do something like this:

```
name: Build
on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
env:
  WITH_IMAGE: '{"image": "my-docker/container:0.1.0"}'
  NO_IMAGE: '{"image": null}'
jobs:
  build:
    strategy:
      matrix:
        os: [ubuntu-latest, macos-latest]
        container: [WITH_IMAGE, NO_IMAGE]
        exclude:
          - os: ubuntu-latest
            container: NO_IMAGE
          - os: macos-latest
            container: WITH_IMAGE
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}
    container: ${{ fromJSON(env[matrix.container]) }}
    steps:
      - (…)
```

I haven't tested this, so it may need some tweaks, but hopefully it conveys the gist of the solution.  This is based on [this GitHub documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/using-a-matrix-for-your-jobs#excluding-matrix-configurations) and a similar issue I encountered recently: [Conditional use of container depending on the group it runs-on for GitHub Actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76925314/conditional-use-of-container-depending-on-the-group-it-runs-on-for-github-action)

Essentially, it uses exclusions so you only get the combinations you want, then passes a null image to container when you don't want to use a container.

Comment: The key point in this answer is that it is possible to pass `null` as an image to `container` which effectively disables Docker when needed. Then the strategy for passing a dynamic value to `container` can differ: it can be as @Shawn described here, or using [paired values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68940067) or just using something like: `container: ${{ matrix.os == 'ubuntu-latest' && 'my-docker/container:0.1.0' || null }}` (refer to [Expressions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#example)). Also note that while passsing `null` works, it seems undocumented.

Answer (score 1):

### Fundamentals

A job can be configured to run directly in the GitHub Actions runner machine by setting [`jobs.<job_id>.container`](https://docs.github.com/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idcontainer) to [`null`](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#10211-null).

For example, this silly workflow runs the `demo` job in the [`ubuntu-latest`](https://docs.github.com/actions/using-github-hosted-runners/about-github-hosted-runners/about-github-hosted-runners#supported-runners-and-hardware-resources) GitHub Actions runner machine:

```yaml
on: push
jobs:
  demo:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    container: null
    steps:
      - run: echo "Hello, world!"
```

### Job Matrixes

The above information about the effect of setting `jobs.<job_id>.container` to `null` becomes relevant when we consider the use case of a [job matrix](https://docs.github.com/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstrategymatrix) where some jobs should run in a container but others should run in the runner machine directly.

For example, this workflow runs one matrix job in the [`alpine:latest`](https://hub.docker.com/layers/library/alpine/latest/images/sha256-48d9183eb12a05c99bcc0bf44a003607b8e941e1d4f41f9ad12bdcc4b5672f86) container and the other matrix job directly in the `ubuntu-latest` runner machine:

```yaml
on: push
jobs:
  demo:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        container:
          - |
            {
              "image": "alpine:latest"
            }
          - |
            null
    container: ${{ fromJSON(matrix.container) }}
    steps:
      - run: echo "Hello, world!"
```

In order to support configuration of the matrix jobs using [any of the supported keys](https://docs.github.com/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idcontainer) of the `jobs.<job_id>.container` mapping, I chose to use [the `fromJSON` function](https://docs.github.com/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#fromjson). For this approach, the elements of the `jobs.demo.strategy.matrix.container` [sequence](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#sequence) are each a [string](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#literal-style) representing a [JSON](https://www.json.org/) document.