# Matrix with single combination at once only

Tags: github-actions

I'm working on one GitHub Actions workflow where I was using a matrix for this. I want to pass one combination of values to the application at a time and don't want to repeat it. Below is the workflow code which I'm trying:

```
name: test_matrix_workflow
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  test_matrix_workflow:
    runs-on: [ ubuntu-latest ]
    strategy:
      matrix:
        value1: [value1a, value1b]
        value2: [value2a, value2b]
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0
      - name: Print Values
        run: |
          echo "Value 1: ${{ matrix.value1 }}"
          echo "Value 2: ${{ matrix.value2 }}"
```

and I'm expecting a value like the below each time

- 1st set

  ```
  ${{ matrix.value1 }} = value1a
  ${{ matrix.value2 }} = value2a
  ```
- 2nd set

  ```
  ${{ matrix.value1 }} = value1b
  ${{ matrix.value2 }} = value2b
  ```

Comment: The matrix is the _Cartesian product_ of its inputs. So if you have two inputs with two values each, that's four runs in total.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Paired values in github actions matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66025220/paired-values-in-github-actions-matrix)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have this matrix

```
value1: [value1a, value1b]
value2: [value2a, value2b]
```

Which results in 4 combinations (meaning 4 jobs),

```
[value1: value1a, value2: value2a]
[value1: value1b, value2: value2a]
[value1: value1a, value2: value2b]
[value1: value1b, value2: value2b]
```

You can use the `exclude` property to exclude any of these combinations from the strategy matrix.

```
test_matrix_workflow:
  runs-on: ubuntu-latest
  strategy:
    matrix:
      value1: [value1a, value1b]
      value2: [value2a, value2b]
      exclude:
        - value1: value1a
          value2: value2b
        - value1: value1b
          value2: value2a
```

---

Works fine in my testing. Only 2 jobs are created when `exclude` is used. Without `exclude`, 4 jobs are created (all possible values of the matrix).

[image]

Refer to https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/using-a-matrix-for-your-jobs#excluding-matrix-configurations for advanced use-cases.

Comment: Thanks, it worked I have total of 4 values each which comes to 16 combinations and I have excluded 12 of them which are more required, and that resolved my issues, that's for quick response and help

Comment: @KNCK why don't you include the four you want, as suggested on the duplicate I proposed, instead of generating 16 scenarios and explicitly excluding 75% of them.